# Records not being indexed or found with global search

Tags: rest-api, custom-object, search, global-search, indexing

I've come across an issue where Salesforce doesn't seem to be indexing records in a custom object that are created through the REST API. When searching for a record name or external ID no results are found in the global search. ***But, if I go to the record detail page and click "Edit" and Save the record without making any changes at all, it becomes searchable.***

I've also verified that time doesn't seem to fix the issue either, in that even after 2 days the record is still not searchable until the process described above is gone through.

Has anyone else come across an issue like this? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting.. did you try creating the same record through any other API, to ensure it's REST-specific?

Comment: I have not. It also does not happen 100% of the time. Only sometimes. Which is leaving me scratching my head as I have not been able to effectively reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you checking "search all" after searching?  If it's an object you (the user) uses infrequently, Salesforce doesn't display the results unless you click search all after the initial search.

Comment: The object is used frequently and is actually pinned to the top of the left in the search feeds column. But yes, I can confirm that is not the issue @gorav

Comment: The documentation states that the delay before indexing is 15 mins or more. So SFDC doesn't give you a KPI on it.  But 2 days is way out of line. This must be either a bug or a temporary hiccup (indexing queue filled up or something alike). If you can still replicate it, it might we worth logging a case with SFDC support to have them have a look.

Comment: I'd expect you have, but just in case, have you checked [Salesforce Trust](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/) for any issues with the pod that hosts your instance when this issue occurs?

Comment: Not every time, but looking at the history for the instance there hasn't been any issues raised around the time frame in questions. @crmprogdev

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't believe all issues get published or shown in the history, esp if they're not major. I'd expect that some things get spotted and fixed without ever appearing.

Comment: @Guy could you add where this is referenced in the documentation? Only info I see is here which says 1-3 minutes for data volumes up to 9000 rows: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_concepts_search_architecture.htm

Comment: How many records are there for the custom object. In particular, how many are you processing in the REST API request?

Just an odd thought, could there be something odd about the character encoding of the values you are searching for? Then, something in the save process from the WEB UI is correcting it and getting it into the search index as expected.

Comment: Less than 1k total records at the moment. The REST API is only inserting one record at a time. Interesting thought about the odd character, I definitely have not noticed anything out the ordinary. Only way I can test that is to wait to have an issue with another record and take closer look at that point @DanielBallinger

Comment: @Marv-o sorry for not including the reference to the docs! Here is the page where the 15 mins are mentioned: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_how_search_works.htm

Comment: When you edit and save the record, are any triggers, processes or workflow rules updating anything else on the record that may be impacting whether or not it is returned in the search results?

Comment: @Lisa there is a workflow that sets the external id field based on the value from another field, but keep in mind the record is not searchable at all not just via the external id field.

Comment: @jonnybro Hmm, frustrating. This sounds a bit like this issue that I had: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114485/soql-where-x-ina-b-does-return-2-records-but-where-x-a-or-x-b-return. Could you try those queries and see if you get the same results?

Comment: Can you try updating the record with API and check if it becomes indexed to make sure the problem is only for newly created records and not for any other which have got updated.

Comment: And the object has a tab (which makes it searchable in global search)?

Comment: I was also working on this, found this and it is quite helpful https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/02/salesforce-bulk-data-loads-and-full-text-search-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

[see here](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf) it says 15 min or more and has other explanations too

Comment: If you read my initial question more closely you'll see that even after days of waiting, the record was still not searchable. Only after forcing an update to the record from the UI did it become searchable.

Comment: Then this can be an isolated performance issue. Do you have large data and complex sharing rule?